# How can I remove the ® character from multiple multi-page PDFs using PyMuPDF for Camelot in Python?

Tags: python, pdf, data-cleaning, pymupdf, python-camelot

How to remove an illegal character, (®) or editing text, in a PDF using Python, specifically PyMuPDF?

I've been trying for hours to remove a trademark symbol ® from about a thousand multi-page PDFs so that I can scrape the tables data into a csv. Camelot considers trademark symbols ® an illegal character apparently. So I need to remove them somehow.

I have tried several variations of code from Stackoverflow, Bard, and Chatgpt. But to no avail. I am now questioning if it is even possible to edit the text of a pdf, or with one which can handle a ®, as I have tried PyPDF2, and it too considers the ® an illegal character.

Is this possible? Yes? No? Perhaps?

Here is one of the versions I have been using which is largely a mix of stackoverflow and chatGPT:

```
import os  
import fitz  

def replace_text(content, replacements=dict()):  
    lines = content.splitlines()  
    result = ""  
    in_text = False  
    for line in lines:  
        if line == "BT":  
            in_text = True  
        elif line == "ET":  
            in_text = False  
        elif in_text:  
            cmd = line.strip()  
            if cmd.lower() in \['tj', 'tj\\n'\]:  
                replaced_line = line  
                for k, v in replacements.items():  
                    replaced_line = replaced_line.replace(k, v)  
            result += replaced_line + "\\n"  
        else:  
            result += line + "\\n"  
else:  
result += line + "\\n"  
return result
  
def remove_illegal_character(input_file, output_folder):  
filename_base = os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(input_file))\[0\]  
output_file = os.path.join(output_folder, filename_base + ".cleaned.pdf")  
replacements = {"\\xae": ""}  
doc = fitz.open(input_file)  
for page_number in range(len(doc)):  
page = doc\[page_number\]  
blocks = page.getTextBlocks()  
for b in blocks:  
if "\\xae" in b\[4\]: # Text contains the illegal character  
new_text = b\[4\].replace("\\xae", "")  
page.updateText(fitz.Point(b\[0\], b\[1\]), new_text)  
doc.save(output_file)  
doc.close()  
def main():  
input_folder = r'C:\\path'  
output_folder = r'C:\\path'  
\# Iterate over all files in the input folder  
for filename in os.listdir(input_folder):  
if filename.endswith('.pdf'):  
input_file = os.path.join(input_folder, filename)  
\# Remove the illegal character from the PDF file  
remove_illegal_character(input_file, output_folder)  
if \__name_\_ == "\__main_\_":  
main()
```

EDIT: Wow, yeah I am now seeing I may have perhaps jumped the gun a step.

Originally for Camelot I was using variations of:

```
def decode_name_object(name):
    try:
        return NameObject(name.decode('utf-8'))
    except (UnicodeEncodeError, UnicodeDecodeError) as e:
        # Name objects should represent irregular characters
        # with a '#' followed by the symbol's hex number
        if not pdf.strict:
            warnings.warn("Illegal character in Name Object", utils.PdfReadWarning)
            return NameObject(name)
        else:
            # raise utils.PdfReadError("Illegal character in Name Object")
            return NameObject(name)

tables = camelot.read_pdf(r'file.pdf')
```

And I kept getting the same error: Illegal character in Name Object (b'/DocuSign\xae')

Comment: Well, back up.  You're solving the wrong part of the problem.  What's the issue when you have ® in the text?  What error do you get?

Comment: Good point, I have added the original error above. Thank you!

Comment: Is that your code, or is that inside camelot?  It would be really easy to filter out the characters after the call to `name.decode`.  Way easier than trying to modify a thousand PDF files internally.

Comment: Can you post a link to a sample PDF file?

Comment: *"Illegal character in Name Object (b'/DocuSign\xae')"* - This sounds like an error in the software: PDF name objects may be arbitrary byte sequences, so assuming one can decode them using UTF-8 in general is wrong.

Comment: Did you solve the problem with DocuSign\xae?